The Righteousness of God as described in Psalms
This question is about the righteousness of God as described in Psalm 85:10-13 and Psalm 89:14 and the reason for the differences between the Authorised (King James) Version and the New International Version.
Authorised Version Psalm 85: 10, 11, 13:

10 Mercy and truth are met together; righteousness and peace have kissed each other.  11 Truth shall spring out of the earth; and righteousness shall look down from heaven.  13 Righteousness shall go before him; and shall set us in the way of his steps.

New International Version Psalm 85:10, 11, 13:

10 Love and faithfulness meet together, righteousness and peace kiss each other. 11 Faithfulness springs forth from the earth, and righteousness looks down from heaven.  13 Righteousness goes before him and prepares the way for his steps.

Authorised Version Psalm 89:14:

Justice and judgment are the habitation of thy throne; mercy and truth shall go before thy face.

New International Version Psalm 89:14:

Righteousness and justice are the foundations of your throne; love and faithfulness go before you.

Mercy and truth or love and faithfulness meet and go before God?  Truth or faithfulness spring from the earth?  Justice and judgment or righteousness and justice are the habitation of God’s throne?  Or perhaps God’s righteousness is based on justice and judgment?  If so, how can God’s righteousness be linked to peace?
My question seeks to understand why these two translations are so different and how are we to understand the righteousness of God in light of these two translations?

My approach toward the OP’s question hinges on the meaning of the noun אֱמֶת (Strong’s H571 meaning firmness, faithfulness, truth). Looking at its biblical usage, אֱמֶת means faithfulness in the sense of constancy and truth as regards the spoken word or instruction.
Outline of Biblical Usage

I. firmness, faithfulness, truth

truth

as spoken
of testimony and judgment
of divine instruction
truth as a body of ethical or religious knowledge
true doctrine




In search of the connection between the different connotations of אֱמֶת, I turn to the context of psalm 85, a psalm that gives voice to those whose relationship with God has been severed/disrupted because of sin. Remembering how He had done so in the past, they plead to God to restore them once more and wait for Him to speak. It is in contemplating God’s word/reply as that which can bridge the rift between God and men that I see a connection between truth and faithfulness.
First and foremost, the words of verse 10 refer to God’s righteousness – His divine love/mercy, which is manifested in the desire to save that which it loves (v7), and the giving and keeping of His word (v8). It is in the meeting of mercy/love and truth/faithfulness that we approach an understanding of God’s righteousness.
Psalm 85:7-11 KJV

7 Shew us thy mercy, O LORD, and grant us thy salvation.
8 I will hear what God the LORD will speak: for he will
speak peace unto his people, and to his saints: but let them not turn
again to folly.

But the righteousness of God is that which looks down from heaven (v11) to be reflected here on earth (vv 9, 11, 12). It is in this meeting between heaven and earth in and through the word of God that we are saved.
Psalm 85: 9-11 NIV

9 Surely his salvation is near those who fear him,   that
his glory may dwell in our land.
10 Love and faithfulness meet together; righteousness and
peace kiss each other.
11 Faithfulness springs forth from the earth, and
righteousness looks down from heaven.
12 The Lord will indeed give what is good, and our land
will yield its harvest.


It is so important to grasp that it is God's righteousness that is key to answering the Q, so it's good you bring this in. An awful lot more could be said about it, though! Could it not be the case that grasping what God's righteousness truly is will show that God's justice was shown at Golgotha, in such a way as to combine his righteousness with his mercy and truth, and that is what divine justice is all about?

@Nhi "It is in the meeting of mercy/love and truth/faithfulness that we approach an understanding of God’s righteousness."  As mentioned in the comment above, it is God's righteousness that is key to answering my question.

@Anne - I agree, Golgotha can definitely be linked to these verses, and Bethlehem as well. There is much that I have left unsaid and more that I am still trying to comprehend. In sum, I think these verses speak to the righteousness of God that is manifest in His Son on the one hand and the righteousness of faith, its earthly reflection/counterpart, that is shown by Abraham and his descendants on the other.

The meaning of the underlying Hebrew words is rather broad and not as narrow as either the English or Greek equivalent words.  This is why various versions translate them with such a variety of words.  More specifically we have:
חֵסֵד (Chesed) Ps 85:10, 89:14
This word means:

lovingkindness, eg, Gen 19:19, 39:21, Ex 15:13
mercy, usually comes as a result of the lovingkindness of God, Gen 32:11, Isa 63:7, Ps 25:6, 89:2
kindness, eg, 1 Sam 20:15, 2 Sam 16:17, Prov 20:28,
redemption from sin, Ps 25:7, 51:3

אֶמֶת ('emeth) Ps 85:10, 11, 89:14
This word means:

reliability, firmness, Gen 24:48, Prov 11:18, Josh 2:12, Jer 2:21
stability, continuance, Isa 39:8, Esther 9:30, Jer 33:6, Zech 8:19
faithfulness reliability, Neh 7:2, Ex 18:21, 1 Kings 2:4, 3:6, Isa 38:21
truth, 1 Kings 22;16, Jer 9:4, Zech 8:16, Ps 15:2

צֶדֶק (tsedeq) Ps 89:14
This word means:

rightness, righteousness.  This can refer to the acts of God or the acts of rulers, or the righteousness of the law, or Messiah, or the righteousness of judgment/justice

מִשְׁפָט (mishpat)
This word means:

judgement or the attribute of justice.  The context determines which is the appropriate meaning.

Again, these words, especially the first two words, have no direct equivalent in English and so are translated by a variety of words as the OP has documented.
In the specific case of Ps 85, the entire psalm is a celebration of the goodness, mercy, lovingkindness, loving devotion, faithfulness of God to His people.  The word חֵסֵד (Chesed) is particularly difficult to translate, so a large variation is used to convey the meaning such as:

Love (NIV, NAB)
unfailing love (TLV)
steadfast love (ESV, NRSV)
loving devotion (BSB)
mercy (KJV, NKJV, ASV, NHEB)
graciousness (NASB)
lovingkindness (LSB)
faithful love (CSB, HCSB)
gracious love (ISV)
kindness (LSV, YLT)
loyal love (NETB)

Similarly, the second word in Ps 85:10 is also rendered:

truth (NLT, KJV, NKJV, NASB, CSB, HCSB, ASV, etc)
faithfulness (ESV, NIV, BSB, etc)
loyalty (CEV)

Thus, we cannot be too precise/narrow about how these words are translated in English because there is no word that has the same meaning.
